# How to decode Base64 string and download as PDF in Android

Tags: java, android, pdf, base64

In my code I am trying to download a PDF file. I am getting Base64 encode string in data value.
I have to download that file as PDF in my mobile. Please suggest how I can do that. 
Thanks.

```java
@Override
public void onInvoicePDFReceived(InvoiceDownload invoiceDownload) {

    String FileName= invoiceDownload.getFileName();
    String dataValue = invoiceDownload.getData();
    File pdfFile = new File(dataValue,"itemized_FINV00988828-2003M_1032028_20200401_52555550.pdf");//File path
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        if (dataValue != null) {
            fos = context.openFileOutput("myPdf.pdf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            byte[] decodedString = android.util.Base64.decode(dataValue , android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
            fos.write(decodedString);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            fos = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `am getting Base64 encode string in data value.` Then the encoded pdf file will be in that string. After that you should decode the contents of the string to pdf and save as pdf file.

Comment: Could you please help me , how can i do that . I tried some code but not working .

Comment: Well you did not tell what was not working. You let us guess in this way.

Comment: Have you looked at the value of pdfFile.getAbsolutePath()? Please tell the value.

Comment: I tried above code , I found on google , nothing happening in thta . If you have piece of code please help

Comment: And if there is an Exception? How would you know? Never leave a catch block empty or unused. Print the stack trace and display a toast to inform the user.

Comment: You are not using pdfFile. So why is it there?

Comment: `nothing happening in thta .`. You did not tell how you would see that something happened or how you checked that.

Comment: The code is not that bad and will do what you want. But you dont see it

Comment: aftr running the code , nothing is gettning save in my mobile , actually i an new I dont know complete flow in android , follwing google

Comment: Well the code will save. So the question was how did you check that? And where did you expect to find the file?

Comment: I was trying something , now am able to open pdf file  iits coming .. but not getting downlaod in local.  That I am trying

Comment: Thank you so much for your time..  if i'll stcuck I'll message u :)